# После заливки сайта на сервер Bootstrap Slider вместо последнего слайда отображает белый фон

Tags: bootstrap

После заливки сайта на сервер Bootstrap Slider вместо последнего слайда отображает белый фон. Если открыть html файл на диске, то всё работает нормально:

```
<section id="main-slider" class="no-margin">
        <div class="carousel slide wet-asphalt">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(images/slider/Sri-Lanka_1.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="carousel-content centered">
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-1">Ð¨Ñ€Ð¸-Ð›Ð°Ð½ÐºÐ°</h2>
                                    <a class="btn btn-md animation animated-item-3" href="Sri-Lanka.html">Ð Ñ‚ÑƒÑ‚ Ð´ÐµÑ‚Ð°Ð»Ð¸...</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/.item-->
                <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/Turkey_1.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="carousel-content centered">
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-1">Ð¢ÑƒÑ€Ñ†Ð¸Ñ</h2>
                                    <a class="btn btn-md animation animated-item-3" href="Turkey.html">Ð Ñ‚ÑƒÑ‚ Ð´ÐµÑ‚Ð°Ð»Ð¸...</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/.item-->
                <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/Georgia_1.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="carousel-content centered">
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-1">Ð“Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð¸Ñ</h2>
                                    <a class="btn btn-md animation animated-item-3" href="Georgia.html">Ð Ñ‚ÑƒÑ‚ Ð´ÐµÑ‚Ð°Ð»Ð¸...</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/.item-->
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/Ukraine_1.jpg)">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="carousel-content centered">
<h2 class="animation animated-item-1">Ð§ÐµÑ€Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ñ†Ñ‹</h2>
<a class="btn btn-md animation animated-item-3" href="Chernovtsy.html">Ð Ñ‚ÑƒÑ‚ Ð´ÐµÑ‚Ð°Ð»Ð¸...</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--/.carousel-inner-->
</div>
<!--/.carousel-->
<a class="prev hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a>
<a class="next hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение. В последней (четвертой картинке) файл был указан следующий: images/slider/Ukraine_1.JPG
а сама картинка имела название: Ukraine_1.jpg.
Т.е. на сервере формат .JPG не распознавался - принимает только .jpg